# Clipboard/file sharing support in Ubuntu virtual machines on Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu-12.04, azure-virtual-machine, xrdp

I've created a new **Ubuntu 12.04** virtual machine on Azure.
Then using

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

installed the standard Ubuntu and **xrdp** which implements the RDP protocol.

Going to Azure portal and downloading *.rdp file then logging

[image]

with the following check boxes still doesn't enable clipboard.

[image]

[image]

I've found several reference that suggest installing [**X11RDP**](http://scarygliders.net/2013/10/11/x11rdp-o-matic-version-3-01-now-released/) but i really don't want to unless there is no other option.

Also it seems that

> Text clipboard in xrdp works with certain restrictions.

Am I missing something or copy/pasting files, text is not supported?

Comment: How did you solve your problem in the end?